# An equivalent of convex function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The question is:

$f :[a,b)  \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex, differentiable. If $$f(x)\sim_{b^{-}}\dfrac 1 {(b-x)^\alpha}, \alpha>0$$ Prove that $$f'(x)\sim_{b^{-}}\dfrac a {(b-x)^{\alpha+1}}, \alpha>0$$

I don't get the point of convex. Isn't is derived by a simple differentiation? Will it be wrong without this condition?

Thanks a lot~

Comment: You have two meanings for $a.$

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I'll change the second to alpha. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As for why "convex" may be important, consider

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{b-x} + \sin\left(\frac{1}{b-x}\right).$$